# Does this code mean 'not equal'?

Tags: javascript

I just want to know if `(clickedNumber === 'Yes or No')` means if the clickedNumber = 'Yes or No', then if I want to say the clickedNumber doesn't equal  'Yes or No', then is it like this:

`(clickedNumber !== 'Yes or No')`?

Thanks

Comment: That does NOT check if both `clickedNumber !== 'Yes' || clickedNumber !== 'No'`. It just checks that the variable `clickedNumber` does **not** literally equal `Yes or No`.

Comment: Are you checking that the string is equal to the `'Yes or No'` string, or if it's equal to *either* `'Yes'` or `'No'`?

Comment: Well the problem is I cannot see the difference because of a mishap in my code. (Long story). So I can't test it so I want to know if this is how it is done

Comment: Yes and No is in one string, I am not checking for both

Comment: If you're checking that a string value is equal to `Yes or No`, then yes, you are right (in this case, not sure that `!=` wouldn't be the same, since type checking is a bit of a non-issue in this case).

Answer (score 10):

The code you've quoted checks to see if the variable `clickedNumber` is [*strictly equal*](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.6) to the string `"Yes or No"`. The opposite of that is `clickedNumber !== 'Yes or No'`, but it's important to understand what you're dealing with.

If `clickedNumber` is `'Yes'`, then `clickedNumber === 'Yes or No'` is false, because `'Yes'` is not strictly (or loosely) equal to `'Yes or No'`. Strict equality (`===`) means:

- The operands are of the same type (this is why it's "strict" rather than "loose"; "loose" equality allows casting, for instance `1 == "1"`).
- **If** the operands are of the same type, they have the same value.

Naturally `'Yes or No'` and `'Yes'` do not have the same value (they **do** have the same type).

If you genuinely do want to check against `'Yes or No'`, fair enough, but if your goal is to check against `'Yes'` or `'No'`, individually, you must do that expressly:

```
if (checkedNumber === 'Yes' || checkedNumber === 'No') {
    // checkedNubmer is 'Yes' **or** it's 'No'
}
```

...the opposite of which is

```
if (checkedNumber !== 'Yes' && checkedNumber !== 'No') {
    // checkedNubmer is neither 'Yes' **nor** 'No'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> if I want to say the clickedNumber doesn't equal 'Yes or No', then is it like this:
>
> `(clickedNumber !== 'Yes or No')`

What you said is correct, but it might not give the results you expect.

For example, what you currently have just checks if the string `clickedNumber` is equal to the string `'Yes or No'`:

```
var clickedNumber = 'Yes or No';

if(clickedNumber === 'Yes or No')
{
    alert("check 1"); // this will be triggered
}

if(clickedNumber !== 'Yes or No')
{
    alert("check 2"); // this will *not* be triggered
}

if(clickedNumber === 'Yes')
{
    alert("check 3"); // this will *not* be triggered
}

if(clickedNumber === 'No')
{
    alert("check 4"); // this will *not* be triggered
}
```

It doesn't use the contents of that string to define any boolean logic, so the word `or` doesn't actually do anything - it just just part of a string:

```
var clickedNumber = 'Yes';

if(clickedNumber === 'Yes or No')
{
    alert("check 1"); // this will *not* be triggered
}

if(clickedNumber !== 'Yes or No')
{
    alert("check 2"); // this will be triggered
}

if(clickedNumber === 'Yes')
{
    alert("check 3"); // this will be triggered
}

if(clickedNumber === 'No')
{
    alert("check 4"); // this will *not* be triggered
}
```

If you want boolean logic to apply, then you'll have to use boolean operators in code rather than in the contents of a string:

```
var clickedNumber = 'Yes';

if(clickedNumber === 'Yes' || clickedNumber === 'No')
{
    alert("check 1"); // this will be triggered
}

if(clickedNumber !== 'Yes' && clickedNumber !== 'No')
{
    alert("check 2"); // this will *not* be triggered
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The code you mentioned:

```
(clickedNumber !== 'Yes or No')
```

Will evaluate as `true` if `clickedNumber` is not equal to the string `'Yes or No'`. It will evalue as `false` if `clickedNumber` is the string `'Yes or No'`.

Note that this is not the same as testing whether it is not equal to either of the two separate strings `'Yes'` or `'No'`, which you would do like this:

```
!(clickedNumber === 'Yes' || clickedNumber === 'No')
```

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators